# \\ComputerName is not accessible do not have permission to access folder

Tags: windows, shared-folders

Additional message:

account disabled

This truly angers me.

I tried to access a network drive. At first I was asked for log on information. At that time I didn't know the logon information, put a wrong one and then save credentials.

Now I can't access it anymore. I am not asked to change credentials. Looks like windows save the credentials and there is no easy way to delete it.

I tried http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263936

It tells to delete computer from active users. It doesn't tell how should I delete such user and how do I access this so called active directory and users

Comment: Tried rebooting? Or try to map it as a network drive and provide another credentials?

Comment: Try `net use \\computername\sharename /user:xxx *` from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the command prompt type:

```
net use \\computername\sharename /delete
```

Obviously, put the appropriate computer and share into the path.  This will delete any saved credentials for that share.

Comment: C:\Users\Jim>net use \\gusyanto /delete
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.


C:\Users\Jim>

Answer (score 1):

I went to control panel Credential Manager.

I delete that computer and it works again.